# How to get the current route's controller (or scope)?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a controller that needs a thing provided by a route resolve function:

```
$routeProvider.when('/some/url', {
  controller: MyController,
  controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
  resolve: {
    theAnswer: ['deepThought', function(deepThought) {
      return deepThought.computeTheAnswerAndReturnAPromise();
    }]
  }
});

var MyController = ['$route', function($route) {
  this.theAnswer = $route.current.theAnswer;
}];
```

Now I want to do an end-to-end test, checking that the route matches and that parameters are propagated properly:

```
// ...set up the routes...

$location.path('/some/url');
$rootScope.$digest();

var ctrl = ???;
expect(ctrl.aThing).toBe(42);
```

In the non-test setup, I can put in a log statement and see that the controller is being created successfully and gets the correct data injected. **The only problem is: how to get hold of the controller in the test?**

- There is `$route.current.controller`, but it contains the controller's constructor function and not the controller instance.
- The [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route) promises a `$route.current.locals.$scope`, from which I could get `myCtrl`, but the `$scope` property doesn't actually exist unless we also use `ngView` (it gets set [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L264)).
- The controller isn't registered with any module, so I can't use `$provide` to intercept its creation and stash the controller somewhere.

Comment: Can't you use [`$controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) to pass in the constructor returned by `$route.current.controller` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, thanks to @PSL's comment. The thing that actually constructs the controller is the `ngView` link function. We can fake that easily enough:

```
var ctrl = $controller(MyController, $route.current.locals);
```